# Thingsboard professional

Tags: javascript, coding-style, thingsboard, card, thingsboard-gateway

I'm nitin pandey,

I want to know that how can I add the javaScript condition in alarm cards professional version of thingsboard. if the temperature level is high then it should be the RED background color and if temperature is normal then it should GREEN with background color. i have added the image for some idea but its a images of community version,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHiZB.png)

thanks in advance

i want answer regarding thingsboard

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>HTML with Condition Nitin Pandey</title>
</head>   
<body>
    <div id='pk' style="background-color: gray; padding: 0px;"> <h5 style="display: inline-block;">Motor_Health </h5>
        <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1tBN6pzVgymvApAspixX">
            <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1tBN6pzVgymvApAspixX" alt="Alarm_Icon" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-left: 90px; margin-top: 5px;">
        </a>
        <div></div>
</div>
    <script>
    var token = localStorage.getItem("jwt_token");
    console.log(token);
        // Function to update the temperature display
        function updateTemperature(temperature) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var pkElement = document.getElementById('pk');
            
            if (temperature > 50) {
                div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                div.style.fontSize = "18px";
                div.style.color = "white";
                div.style.height = "200px";
                div.textContent = "Temperature: " + temperature + "°C (High)";
            } else if (temperature > 40) {
                div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                div.style.fontSize = "18px";
                div.style.color = "black";
                div.style.height = "200px";
                div.textContent = "Temperature: " + temperature + "°C (Moderate)";
            } else {
                div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                div.style.fontSize = "18px";
                div.style.color = "white";
                div.style.height = "200px";
                div.textContent = "Temperature: " + temperature + "°C (Low)";
            }
            //it is deleting and replacing by new temperature data everytime
pkElement.removeChild(pkElement.lastElementChild);
            pkElement.appendChild(div);
        }

        // Fetch data from an API
        var apiUrl = 'http://68.178.167.12:8080/api/plugins/telemetry/DEVICE/b6b0-5dcf-11ee-a906-ebdb/values/timeseries?keys=temperature';
        var Auth = 'Bearer ' + token; 
        var headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Authorization': Auth
        });

        // Function to fetch and update temperature data
        function fetchAndUpdateTemperature() {
            // Clear the existing content in the pk element
            const pkElement = document.getElementById('pk');
            //pkElement.innerHTML = '';
        
            fetch(apiUrl, { method: 'GET', headers: headers })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        return response.json();
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Request failed with status ' + response.status);
                    }
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('API Response:', data); // Add this line for debugging
        
                    if (data.temperature && data.temperature.length > 0) {
                        const temperatureValue = data.temperature[0].value;
                        updateTemperature(temperatureValue);
                    } else {
                        console.error('No temperature data found.');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
        
        // Fetch and update temperature immediately
        fetchAndUpdateTemperature();
        
        // Refresh temperature data every 10 seconds
        const refreshInterval = 10000; // 10 seconds in milliseconds
        setInterval(fetchAndUpdateTemperature, refreshInterval);

    </script>
</body>
</html>



By doing this we can add the condition inside the HTML of thingsboard. it will taket he user input as a temperature from the different port. and show the what we want
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).